# How to use more DOS commands in C#

Tags: c#, dos, process

I have about 7 commands in DOS and I want to run them in my C# program. Can I do:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "my more commands here");
```

?
**EDIT:**
I'm making small app what will run g++. Is this now correct?:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k cd C:\\Alps\\compiler\\ /k g++ C:\\Alps\\" + project_name + "\\Debug\\Main.cpp");
```

Command for compiling:

```
g++ -c C:\Alps\here_is_projectname\Debug\Main.cpp -o main.o
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cmd.exe /k <command>
cmd.exe /c <command>
```

Are both valid.

- **`/k`** will execute the command and leave you with an empty prompt (probably less desirable in your application if you just want to execute for feedback.)
- **`/c`** will execute the command and close the window when it has completed.

If you're looking to execute a command from a specific directory, you can do:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"/c g++ ""C:\Alps\{0}\Debug\Main.cpp""", project_name);
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Alps\compiler";
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
p.Start();
```

Comment: /k is better for me. Thanks. And one more small question: will cmd start in C# application path (in vs default mydocs.....\bin\debug)? I need more commands so /c is bad for me.

Comment: @FrewCen: To be honest, I don't recall. However, you can modify the [`ProcessStartInfo.WorkingPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) to have it run where ever you'd like.

Comment: @FrewCen: My apologies, I didn't include the `/c` flag in the `StartInfo.Arguments` assignment.

Comment: ok, but can you please look on ful command and edit your code, because you have there many '"' and i don't know how to edit that code in that line. Where can I add  -c and -o ?

Comment: @FrewCen: Why don't you call `g++.exe` directly then out of curiosity? Why do you pipe the command through `cmd.exe` first?

Comment: cause g++ is in alps.... wait. One probably silly question: will system.diagnostic.process.start() run batch file?

Comment: @FrewCen: I'm not sure I understand the limitation. You can set the working directory or directly call g++ given its path. Also, you can execute batch, but I recommend calling it as an argument to cmd.exe. e.g. `cmd.exe /c myBatchFile.bat`

Comment: Look: I have this code: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Alps\\compiler\\H-i586-cygwin32\\bin\\g++.exe", " -c Main.cpp -o Main.o");` whz it does not works? Can you see any error?

Comment: @FrewCen: Remembert hat g++ will look for "main.cpp" in its own folder. Make sure to reference the full path in the arguments. e.g. `Process.Start("C:\\alps\\compiler\\...\\g++.exe", "-c C:\\alps\\project_name\\...\\main.cpp -o ...");`

Comment: Look: http://prntscr.com/2l7nf I have this error bu tcygwin1.dll is there. Why???

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can pass in the command line using the "/C" switch:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C dir");
```

Comment: @chibacity: Sorry, edited your answer not mine. My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do like the following....

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
{
 Arguments = "args",
 WorkingDirectory = "C:\SomePath",
 UseShellExecute= true,
 FileName = ".exe"
});
```

There are also options on the processstartinfo to redirect input and output if you need to

For example..

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
{
 Arguments = "C:\\Alps\\" + project_name + "\\Debug\\Main.cpp",
 WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Apls\\",
 UseShellExecute= true,
 FileName = "g++.exe"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can launch cmd.exe redirect the stdin and feet that stream with your commands.

```
 process.Start(...);


                    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("Dir xxxxx");
                    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("Dir yyyyy");
                    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("Dir zzzzzz");
                    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("other command(s)");
```

Of course you should remeber to set your process star info to say you want redirect input:

```
 ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe);
        processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        processStartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
```

Comment: @FrewCen process in my example is an instance of process, not the class.